# Error when using glmulti with aicc?

Tags: r

Could you let me know if you know the solution to the error I get when I run glmulti with the aicc criteria:

Error in if (length(lesCrit) == confsetsize && minouN - minou >= -deltaM &&  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

It goes away when the confsetsize is low (~5).

Thanks!

Comment: Not enough information. Please give us a reproducible example.

Comment: I would be happy if anyone else had encountered this error before and solved it. I can't find mention via google. I will add the code to reproduce it if no one has ever solved it before but it will take a while to build the dataset and modify my code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a incrementing variable called "lesCrit" and in order to stop confsetssize must be equal to it.

If it is too small then premature termination would occur.

It needs to be set so that an equality comparison can be made.